# DNS for home network with dnsmask: doesn't change IPs

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, dns, dnsmasq, mdns

I've got a home network: three hosts on OS X and printer. All the devices are wireless and connected into a network via Actiontech T1200H router which is also provides internet. One computer(MacPro) works as a server and never switched off.

But for now DNS and DHCP services provided by router (which I've got from my ISP)...

Is it possible to use Dnsmasq to override the services provided by router?

my **dnsmasq.conf**:

```
port=5353
interface=en2
dhcp-range=192.168.1.70,192.168.1.250,12h

# Static IP addresses for home WLAN:
dhcp-host=c8:bc:c8:d4:b9:e8,my.macbookpro.local,192.168.1.60
dhcp-host=80:00:6e:f1:c3:4a,my.macpro.local,192.168.1.61
dhcp-host=84:85:06:97:4C:95,my.ipad.local,192.168.1.62
dhcp-host=00:26:ab:6c:f7:fc,my.epson.local,192.168.1.63

expand-hosts
domain=drew-sh.org

# My router's IP:
dhcp-option=option:router,192.168.1.254

# Web dev settings:
address=/.dev/127.0.0.1
# to listen for DHCP and DNS requests on addresses:
listen-address=127.0.0.1

# Google public DNS:
server=8.8.8.8
server=8.8.4.4
```

I've restarted dnsmasq multiple times, but old IP addresses of all devices did not change... What am I doing wriong?

**EDIT:**

after I logged in to my router and go to **WAN Settings** I've found this options:

```
Select the ISP protocol below.
     PPPoE
   * RFC 1483 via DHCP
     RFC 1483 via Static IP`
```

and when I switch to `PPPoE` (by default it is `RFC 1483 via DHCP`) getting:

```
Enter your PPP username and password.
    PPP Username:   
    PPP Password:
```

Is that what you mean by "specific ISP/gateway combination for administrative password"?

Comment: Did you try renewing your IP on clients, they will not change IP until their lease expires? https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18513?locale=en_US

Comment: Also disable DHCP services on your router. Having two DHCP servers on a network is not a good thing.

Comment: Thank you for reply! I've tried it but seems like Actiontech T1200H router does not allow to disable DHCP...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you will need to disable DHCP on your router (or change it to give out your new DNS server addresses), having two on a network is not a good thing.

Second you will need to renew DHCP lease on every device, because devices will not do it automatically until their lease expires.

You've mentioned you can't turn DHCP off on your Actiontec T1200H, but to quote [the manual](http://www.manualslib.com/manual/816410/Actiontec-T1200h.html?page=49&term=dhcp&selected=14):

> "To change the Gateway's DHCP settings:
>   1. Click Enable to activate the Gateway's DHCP server."

Now what some telecommunications companies do is they give you a username and password that is limited to setting up WiFi, rebooting and doing some other basic settings. What they don't tell you about is there is another set of credentials to allow full control over the router. You don't get these because you can screw it up and they have to come to your house to fix it.

Try calling your ISP and asking for this administrative user/password (good luck with that) and try Google searching your specific ISP/gateway combination for administrative password, someone probably figured it out.

__EDIT

PPoE settings are for [VPN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network), and DHCP can assign IPs to VPN clients, but it's not DHCP itself.

Here is an example of what I mean:

I use Telekom Srbija as ISP and they gave me a username "user" and password "123456" to log into my gateway. This user can't change DHCP settings.
[image]

So I went online and typed into Google search "Telekom Srbija ADSL admin user" and it came up with username "admin" and password "adminpassword". Logging in with these gave a much different menu and access to changing DHCP.
[image]

Comment: I've updated the post... please take a look